# Predict v.s. transform for sklearn.cluster.KMeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I am currently looking at a data science project in which I have a data set which contains three feature columns:

- latitude, longitude (which are floats)
- area which is a categorical variable with 3 values.

I would like to run a clustering algorithm (KMeans) on the latitude and longitude column to do so, wrote this custom transformer which extracts one or more columns from a pandas Dataframe

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import pandas as pd
class SelectColumns(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns):
         '''
        columns: list or array of columns to extract
        '''
        self.columns = columns

    def transform(self, data_train):
        '''
        data_train: Pandas dataframe of which we want to extract the columns
        '''
        return data_train[self.columns]

    def fit(self, *_):
        return self
```

Then, I chain it with KMeans in a Pipeline:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
SelectPosition = SelectColumns(columns=['latitude', 'longitude'])
Clustering = Pipeline([('SelectPosition', SelectPosition),
    ('Clustering', KMeans())])
SelecCategoricalVariable = SelectColumns(columns=['area'])
FinalPipeline = FeatureUnion([('cat',SelecCategoricalVariable),
                              ('cluster',Clustering)])
```

The issue is that when I run `FinalPipeline.fit_transform()` which is the only method available (I do not know why fit_predict is not available) the columns which should contain the cluster my variable beongs returns a float which I believe is the distance fo of my variable to the center of my cluster. Would any of you have an idea why this happen and if it is possible to force the KMeans predictor to behave as I would like. 
Thanks for your help

When I run 
`FinalPipeline.fit_predict(data)` I obtain `AttributeError: type object 'FeatureUnion' has no attribute 'fit_predict'
​`
Here is an example of the data I want to fit

```
air            latitude         longitude
Dining bar     35.641463    139.698171
Dining bar     35.662665    139.668268
Dining bar     35.693840    139.703549
Bar/Cocktail   35.670651    139.771861
Japanese food  35.712607    139.779996
Izakaya            35.743575    139.847180
Izakaya        35.693840    139.703549
```

Comment: I obtain a `AttributeError: type object 'FeatureUnion' has no attribute 'fit_predict'​`

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry I saw it now. You are using the FeatureUnion wrong. Do you want to first combine the features from `SelectPosition` and `SelecCategoricalVariable` and then use KMeans to predict on them?

Comment: What does `data` variable contain and you're trying to pass it in `fit_predict`?

Comment: Nope, I want to run KMeans only on latitude and longitude columns and then concatenate the result with the the area column. I want to run KMeans clustering on the latitude and longitude column  (`Clustering`) and join the result (cluster of each elment with the `area` column of my data.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous are categorical variables and longitude ans latitude contain floats. I will ad an example in my message

Comment: Ok Understood. But that cannot be current setup. Because featureUnion will not allow `fit_predict` and when you use `fit_transform()`, the internal estimators will also call `fit_transform()` and not `predict()`. You can do this by making a custom class though. From that class, override the transform() method to return the predict() method.

Comment: Great, I think this solves my problem :).